# Highlighting a class in the package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a plugin in Eclipse which adds an option to the Package Explorer for searching a class. So the plugin searches for the class and it returns back the class path.
Then it should highlight the class in the explorer.

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me regarding the highlighting the class.

I tried this:

```
file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(myPath);
if (file != null ) {
        //Select the data file
        IViewReference[] views =     PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
        for(IViewReference view:views){
            if("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())){
                IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
                pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(--);
                break;
            }
        }
```

However, I have only the file path and I couldn't manage to create a structuredSelection or something like that which is required as a param for setSelection.

Comment: I tried this:file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(myPath);
if (file != null ) {
            //Select the data file
            IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
            for(IViewReference view:views){
                if("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())){
                    IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
                    pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider().setSelection(--);
                    break;
                }
            }

Comment: Generally, it is better to describe what you have tried into your question. So I highly suggest you to put your code into your question. Then people can answer your question more specifically.